# Order Columns in Dataset from Largest to Smallest Value in A Specified Row

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
library(data.table)

dat1<-data.table(id=c(111,111,111,222,222,222), year=c(1995,1996,1997,1995,1996,1997), value=c(4,5,1,2,6,7))
```

How do I order the columns of the dataset based on the size of the values in row 1 (or an arbitrary row).

I want my output to be:

```
dat2<-data.table(value=c(4,5,1,2,6,7),id=c(111,111,111,222,222,222), year=c(1995,1996,1997,1995,1996,1997)
```

Because in dat1 row 1, value 4 is the smallest value making "dat1$value" column 1, id 111 is second smallest value making "dat1$id" column 2 and year 1995 is biggest value making "dat1$year" column 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `setcolorder`

```
setcolorder(dat1, names(dat1)[order(dat1[1])])
dat1
   value  id year
1:     4 111 1995
2:     5 111 1996
3:     1 111 1997
4:     2 222 1995
5:     6 222 1996
6:     7 222 1997
```

Method 2

```
dat1 = dat1[,names(dat1)[order(dat1[1,])],with=F]
   value  id year
1:     4 111 1995
2:     5 111 1996
3:     1 111 1997
4:     2 222 1995
5:     6 222 1996
6:     7 222 1997
```

Recommend by RonakShah

```
dat1[, order(dat1[1, ]), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: I know the example is in data.table but do you have an idea of how to use the "order" command to do this in base R?

Comment: @RonakShah thank you :-) would you mind I updated it ?